# Dropdownlist change event not triggering in Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I got stuck on a weird problem in asp.net. I've a Modal Pop Up window in which I've many controls and a GridView too. The GridView further contains Drop Down List. I want to trigger  DropDown SelectIndexChange event when user select any option from dropdown list. But everytime when I try to change the option value is never triggers the event of drop down list. I'm sharing my complete code for this problem .

**This is my GridView in which I've drop down list and may update panel and triggers tag.**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewNewRates" Style="width: auto" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" runat="server" ShowFooter="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridViewNewRates_RowDataBound">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate UOM" HeaderStyle-CssClass="text-center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">                                                     
                                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_RateUOM" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_RateUOM_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="40" CssClass="ddlist1" runat="server">
                                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                                    <Triggers>                                                          
                                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl_RateUOM" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                                    </Triggers>                                                   
                                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>                                       
                                    </Columns>                                  
                                </asp:GridView>
```

**In my code behind file I have Change Event**

```
   protected void ddl_RateUOM_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I've tried almost many solutions but none of them worked for me...
Thanks

Comment: Does your form contains a button which has ID="submit"?? I had a similar problem and it was the problem with button having ID=submit.. Weird but true.

Comment: Have you tried taking out the update panel and confirming the postback is actually working?  How about removing the async postback trigger and setting updatepanel updatemode = always?  Did you make sure you aren't rebinding the grid on postback also?